# Проблема с фильтром таблицы HTML

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, table

Есть таблица которая подгружается из БД. Хотел сделать "выпадающий" фильтр для каждого столбца, но выдает ошибку.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Инвентаризация</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "eel.js">

    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="add">Добавить</button>
            <button id="btn">Изменить</button>
            <button id="delete">Удалить</button>
            <button id="update">Обновить</button>
        </div>
    </div>   
    
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Поиск по таблице" id="search-text" onkeyup="tableSearch()"    >         
            
    <div class="box2">
        <table id="table">
            <tbody>
                <th>№ п/п</th>
                <th col-index = 1>Расположение
                    <select class="table-filter">
                        <option value="all"></option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th col-index = 2>Наименование
                    <select class="table-filter">
                        <option value="all"></option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th col-index = 3>Серийный номер
                    <select class="table-filter">
                        <option value="all"></option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th col-index = 4>Инвентарный номер
                    <select class="table-filter">
                        <option value="all"></option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("#delete").onclick = function(){
    
    var unique_col_values_dict = {}

    allFIlters = document.querySelectorAll(".table-filter")
    allFIlters.forEach(filter_i => {
        col_index = filter_i.parentElement.getAttribute("col-index");
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table > tbody > tr" )
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            cell_value = row.querySelector("td:nth-child("+col_index+")").innerHTML;
            if (col_index in unique_col_values_dict) {

                if (unique_col_values_dict[col_index].includes(cell_value)){
                    alert(cell_value +"is already present in array" + unique_col_values_dict[col_index])
                    
                } else {
                    unique_col_values_dict[col_index].push(cell_value)
                    alert("Array after adding the cell value " + unique_col_values_dict[col_index])
                }

            } else {
                unique_col_values_dict[col_index] = new Array(cell_value)
            }
        
        });

    });

    for(i in unique_col_values_dict) {
        alert("Column index : " + i + " has unique values : \n" + unique_col_values_dict[i]);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at main.js:13:74
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:12:14
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at document.querySelector.onclick (main.js:9:16)
```

И еще строки в таблице создаются автоматически и заполняются туда же, где и заголовки таблицы(скрин ниже), как это все можно исправить?[image: Готовая таблица]

Comment: Ошибка в `row.querySelector("td:nth-child("+col_index+")")`, не находит элемент по этому селектору, проверьте поиск элемента

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function или Cannot read property \*\*\* of undefined or null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-cannot-re)